# React object expression?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following `render` function:

```
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Sign Up Sheet</h1>

    <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>

      <Field
        placeholder='Name'
        name='name'
        value={this.state.fields.name}
        onChange={this.onInputChange}
        validate={(val) => (val ? false : 'Name Required')}
      />

      <br />

      <Field
        placeholder='Email'
        name='email'
        value={this.state.fields.email}
        onChange={this.onInputChange}
        validate={(val) => (isEmail(val) ? false : 'Invalid Email')}
      />

      <br />

      <CourseSelect
        department={this.state.fields.department}
        course={this.state.fields.course}
        onChange={this.onInputChange}
      />

      <br />

      {{
        SAVING: <input value='Saving...' type='submit' disabled />,
        SUCCESS: <input value='Saved!' type='submit' disabled />,
        ERROR: <input
          value='Save Failed - Retry?'
          type='submit'
          disabled={this.validate()}
        />,
        READY: <input
          value='Submit'
          type='submit'
          disabled={this.validate()}
        />,
      }[this.state._saveStatus]}

    </form>

    <div>
      <h3>People</h3>
      <ul>
        { this.state.people.map(({ name, email, department, course }, i) =>
          <li key={i}>{[ name, email, department, course ].join(' - ')}</li>
        ) }
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
   );
  }
 };
```

What is that for an expression?

```
  {{
    SAVING: <input value='Saving...' type='submit' disabled />,
    SUCCESS: <input value='Saved!' type='submit' disabled />,
    ERROR: <input
      value='Save Failed - Retry?'
      type='submit'
      disabled={this.validate()}
    />,
    READY: <input
      value='Submit'
      type='submit'
      disabled={this.validate()}
    />,
  }[this.state._saveStatus]}
```

It is an object?

Comment: You would really like to understand the higher-order component(HoC). https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the object based on the saved status it will return you the desired JSX element. For Instance if `this.state._saveStatus` is `SAVING`, it will return you `<input value='Saving...' type='submit' disabled />`

```
{{
    SAVING: <input value='Saving...' type='submit' disabled />,
    SUCCESS: <input value='Saved!' type='submit' disabled />,
    ERROR: <input
      value='Save Failed - Retry?'
      type='submit'
      disabled={this.validate()}
    />,
    READY: <input
      value='Submit'
      type='submit'
      disabled={this.validate()}
    />,
  }[this.state._saveStatus]}
```

You can think of the above like

```
render() {
    const obj = {
        SAVING: <input value='Saving...' type='submit' disabled />,
        SUCCESS: <input value='Saved!' type='submit' disabled />,
        ERROR: <input
          value='Save Failed - Retry?'
          type='submit'
          disabled={this.validate()}
        />,
        READY: <input
          value='Submit'
          type='submit'
          disabled={this.validate()}
        />,
      }

      return (
          <div>{obj[this.state._saveStatus]}</div>
       )
}
```

Now it is fairly inefficient to do what you are doing, since on each state change, a new element is returned. Instead what you need to do is change just the value and disabled attribute of input

```
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Sign Up Sheet</h1>

    <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>

      <Field
        placeholder='Name'
        name='name'
        value={this.state.fields.name}
        onChange={this.onInputChange}
        validate={(val) => (val ? false : 'Name Required')}
      />

      <br />

      <Field
        placeholder='Email'
        name='email'
        value={this.state.fields.email}
        onChange={this.onInputChange}
        validate={(val) => (isEmail(val) ? false : 'Invalid Email')}
      />

      <br />

      <CourseSelect
        department={this.state.fields.department}
        course={this.state.fields.course}
        onChange={this.onInputChange}
      />

      <br />

      <MessageField saveStatus={this.state._saveStatus} validate={this.validate()} />

    </form>

    <div>
      <h3>People</h3>
      <ul>
        { this.state.people.map(({ name, email, department, course }, i) =>
          <li key={i}>{[ name, email, department, course ].join(' - ')}</li>
        ) }
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
   );
  }
 };  


const MessageField = ({ saveStatus, validate }) => {
   const value = undefined;
   const disabled = true;
   switch(saveStatus) {
       case 'SAVING': value='Saving...';  disabled=true; break;
       case 'SUCCESS': value='Saved!'; disabled=true; break;
       case 'ERROR': value='Save Failed - Retry?';
          disabled=validate();
          break;
       case 'READY': value='Submit';
          disabled=validate();
          break;
   }
   return <input type={submit} disabled={disabled} value={value} />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an object inside the usual `{...}` JSX expression notation used to embed values, which the code then picks a property from.

The code creates an object (the inner `{}`) and then looks up the property with the name in `this.state._saveStatus` on it; that becomes the value of the `{...}` expression.

So for instance, if `this.state._saveStatus` is `"SUCCESS"`, the overall `{...}` expression evaluates to `<input value='Saved!' type='submit' disabled />`

---

It's a fairly inefficient way to do what it does. It creates an object and several elements (which involves function calls to `React.createElement` under the covers), just to discard them and keep the one it wants. Instead, an SFC would be a better choice (and reusable):

```
const StatusElement = props => {
    switch (props.status) {
        case "SAVING":
            return <input value='Saving...' type='submit' disabled />;
        case "SUCCESS":
            return <input value='Saved!' type='submit' disabled />;
        case "ERROR":
            return <input
                  value='Save Failed - Retry?'
                  type='submit'
                  disabled={props.disabled}
                />;
        case "READY":
            return <input
                  value='Submit'
                  type='submit'
                  disabled={props.disabled}
                />;
    }
};
```

then:

```
<StatusElement status={this.state._saveStatus} disabled={this.validate()} />
```

Answer (score 1):

> It is an object?

Yes. It's [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors), used to get the data by dynamic key.

If you break that, it will become:

```
const obj = {
    SAVING: <input value='Saving...' type='submit' disabled />,
    SUCCESS: <input value='Saved!' type='submit' disabled />,
    ERROR: <input
      value='Save Failed - Retry?'
      type='submit'
      disabled={this.validate()}
    />,
    READY: <input
      value='Submit'
      type='submit'
      disabled={this.validate()}
    />,
}
```

Then getting the value by `this.state._saveStatus` value:

```
{obj[this.state._saveStatus]}
```

Now just replace the `obj` with its content, you will get what you have written in the question. Basically that object contain the mapping of keys with JSX, and `this.state._saveStatus` will have any one key out of `SAVING, SUCCESS, ERROR, READY`. If you see the final result of that expression, then it will be any one JSX.